# What is the C++ equivalent to GetObject in JavaScript and VBScript?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, vbscript, wsh

What is the C++ equivalent to `GetObject` in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)?

The closest match I found to my question is:

http://codewiz51.blogspot.com/2008/06/vb-script-getobject-c-api-cogetobject.html

However the sample use an unexisting interface and asking for the `IUnknown` returns null. Did someone have an example that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The object I wanted to access was

`winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv`

I mistakenly took \\ for an escapement. In C++ the correct query is :

`::CoGetObject(L"winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\default:StdRegProv", NULL, IID_IUnknown, (void**)&pUnk);`

Thank you :)

Comment: That WMI object provides access to the registry. There are easier ways to do it in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked to is correct. You may be providing the wrong interface ID, or the display name could be wrong. You should check the return value from the `CoGetObject` call.

Answer (score 0):

If asking for IUnknown returns NULL, there is no object by that name. Each COM object implements IUnknown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized COM before making any COM calls?

Look up CoInitializeEx.